# Problems when creating screens with Listfield and Buttons

Tags: blackberry, button, listfield

I need to create a screen with a Listfield and three buttons at the bottom of the screen. I tried to make a status bar and put three buttons into. The screen is displayed correctly but I just only be able to click on that buttons when traversing all items in Listfield. Please give me some helps!

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to extend the ListField, intercept the gesture you want to cause a traversal from the list to the status bar (before reaching then end of the list) and change focus programatically.